# cp: illegal option -- b on mac

Tags: macos, backup, cp

I'm looking to backup a file.  If the file exists in backup form, I'm looking to create a new version of that filename so as not to overwrite the previous backup.

I believe:

```
cp -b ~/.profile ~/
cp --backup ~/.profile ~/
```

is exactly what I need.  However these options aren't available on a mac.  Does anyone know if a substitute exists on a mac?

Answer (score 10):

Easiest thing to do is install GNU cp. The easiest way to do that is install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
ruby -e \
  "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install coreutils
```

Then you can use `gcp` instead of `cp` whenever you need features not in the BSD cp that's part of OS X, e.g. `gcp --backup`.

Comment: gcp --backup ~/Downloads/test/chenx*/* ~/Desktop/
why this not work. But : fatal: 不是 git 仓库（或者任何父目录）：.git